# DialogFragment dissmisses or hides after home is pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I am showing a dialogFragment that is not cancelable. But when I press the home button or lock the screen and go back to my application then the dialogFragment dissapears. After that I can click the back button, and when I click the back button and return to the application again the dialog fragment appears again...

```
private void showRoutePauseDialog() {

    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(RouteActivityPausedDialogFragment.TAG);
    if (prev != null) {
        ft.remove(prev);
    }
    ft.commit();

    routeActivityPausedDialogFragment = new RouteActivityPausedDialogFragment();
    routeActivityPausedDialogFragment.setListener(this);
    routeActivityPausedDialogFragment.setCancelable(false);
    routeActivityPausedDialogFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), RouteActivityPausedDialogFragment.TAG);
}
```

This happens only on this dialogfragment. I have other dialogFragments in this fragment and they work fine... I also noticed if I show another dialogFragment (one that works fine) and press home and return to the app and after that show the RouteActivityPausedDialogFragment and press Home and return then this dialogFragment also works fine...

Comment: Maybe you can use a boolean flag which you can store in sharedpreferences. So every time your activity comes to the foreground, check that flag and accordingly do setCancelable(false) for that again.

Comment: this doesn't have anything to do with the cancelable. The problem is that the dialog doesn't show after I get back into the app after I pressed home button.

Comment: So then try calling that dialogFragment from onResume(), so that it will again display after your activity comes back to the foreground.

Comment: Look the problem is if I show another dialogFragment before this dialogFragment then this dialogFragment shows after I press the home button and go back to the app(it displays correctly), but if I don't show another dialogFragment before this dialogFragment then this dialogFragment won't be shown after I return from home button.

So if I show the dialogFragment in onResume, here in the first case the dialogFragment will be shown 2 times and in the second case it will show 1 times (also now correctly)

Comment: I got the same problem any luck resolving this yet?

Comment: yes, i resolved it by setting a Handler in onResume:

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                   showRoutePauseDialog();
                  }
              }, 300);

Loos like this is some bug on Android, and this was the only working solution for me.